# Android Location - how to get current and avoiding nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, geolocation, location, android-studio

I've used the following tutorial (http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) to set up location for my app. I use

```
mLocationClient.getLastLocation().toString()
```

However, this throws a NullPointerException on a phone that is unable to get the location. How would I be able to make it get the current location in the on click of a button and if it's not able to get the current location, to display an error and then keep trying to get the current location?

Thank you very much,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is very less possibility that device won't have location, although, what you can do, catch the `NPE` and wait for few seconds using a Handler, and again ask for the Location using the same code, i.e using `getLastLocation()`.